# Conceptual: Pressure change in closed very long pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, ideal-gas, gas

Let's say I have a very long pipe with a very small diameter with one closed end and a tight fitting piston.

If I pull the piston to increase the volume and/or push the piston to reduce the volume, will the pressure change be felt throughout the volume or only in the vicinity of the piston after a very long time? Assume that the system is kept at a constant temperature.

As per ideal gas law, it seems to me that the pressure change should be felt throughout the volume. However, a colleague suggested that if the loss through the pipe is large then the change is only felt in the vicinity of the piston. Which of these explanations are correct if we observe the pressure after a very long time?

Answer (score 0):

As you are pushing the piston, there will be a greater pressure (or lower pressure, if you pull it backward) in the region in front of the piston, and the pressure in the whole pipe will equalize after a time depending on how long the pipe is once you stop pushing.

The pressure will be the same throughout the volume after this time. If there is no other force that would push on the gas particles to one end (for example, gravity if the pipe is oriented vertically), then there is no reason why the pressure would vary along the pipe after a long time and after the pushing/pulling stops.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: That's OK. Good luck with your studies.